# Trying to get filesize from a file on mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching for a while through here, and several other places via google, and have had no luck finding an answer thus far. Either I'm not using the correct search terms, or no answer exists for my specific issue.

I have a ftp site that is protected by a user-authentication system (only admins can upload and delete files from the server, anyone can download), and I have it fixed to be able to upload the file to the database, but when I view the download page which lists all files available in the database, I get the following error:

> Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /usr/www/cgcserver/public/download.php on line 31

On line 31 of my code for that page, I have:

```
$bytes = filesize($content);
```

The code block for the page pertaining to that line of code is:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, creator, content FROM upload";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "Database is empty <br>";
}
else
{
    while(list($id, $name, $creator, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $bytes = filesize($content);
?>
<tr><td><a href="download.php?id=<?php $id; ?>"><?php $name . ' - ' .bytesToSize($bytes); ?></a></td><td><?php $creator; ?></td></tr>
```

I am trying to pull the filesize from the database, and display it next to the download link so users know how big it is before they download.  The bytesToSize is just a function I have to convert the filesize() into bytes, kb, mb, etc.

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

Please note the file itself is stored in the database in the variable "content"

Comment: What do you have in $content? It should be the real path to the file

Comment: Why have you decided to store the files in the database? Well, anyway, you're storing it as a string, you either need to recreate the file or count bytes per character... But the best way would be to rethink the way you're storing the files, why not just store them on the server?

Comment: I was originally doing just that, storing them on the server, and now it seems that might be the better approach, as now, when I try to download the file from the database, it won't even let me open it, and its filetype is stored as something other than what it actually is.

I was able to fix the original issue just now by completely removed the line causing the issue, and changing content in the query to size (another one of the variables stored), and running that through my bytesToSize function instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of the content stored in the database, use `strlen()`. You can't use `filesize()` because you're not looking at a file.

However, a better solution would be to get the size of the content from the database directly.

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, creator, LENGTH(content) AS size FROM upload";
```